# STM32 LTDC - Maximum resolution

Tags: stm32, resolution, ltdc

I am planning to interface a [STM32H753XI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753xi.html) to a 1400x480 display. Here is the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099.pdf). Now, the maximum resolution given for the STM is 1024x728. I understand that this is the maximum frequency the device can actually output.

Now my desired horizontal resolution exceeds the controllers 1024 pixels. I checked with the registers and they support 11 bit values (so everything up to 2047). Has anyone tried to interface a display with a larger horizontal resolution to an STM? Are the horizontal and vertical pixels a hard limit or is the combined pixel clock frequency the actual limit?

Comment: maximum resolution according to what document??  This is more likely a function of the drivers you've found and the choices made for what peripheral will drive the display than limitations of the microcontroller

Comment: @ScottSeidman according to the website I linked (XGA resolution) and the LTCD peripheral in the STM32. Also, Stm32cubeIde limits the value for the horizontal resolution to 1024 but you could override it.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in the STM32 Q&A forums with a link to [this document](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/25/ca/f9/b4/ae/fc/4e/1e/DM00287603/files/DM00287603.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00287603.pdf).

Basically the limit is the maximum resolution according to the registers (4096x2048) but what is more important is the bandwidth to the framebuffer memory (typically in a connected SDRAM). So it seems that the resolution should be possible but we're already quite near the limit.